# Unable to get vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class?

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am trying to pull data from the sheet "UsedData"(column E) using the same lookup value in column A of Final Pivot, to each of the following columns on final pivot. All of corresponding data is in columns E-L on Used Data.

Everytime I run the macro I get Error 1004 :unable to get vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class

I have tried limiting my range. I have tried showing the selection of each set. I have tried C1 = an actual vlookup formula ie (vlookup=A:A, UsedData!E:E, 3, FALSE). This one did give me a "#Name", instead of nothing.

I have manually did the vlookup in excel and it works fine.

```
Sub Trial()
Workbooks("Final SOR.xlsm").Sheets("UsedData").Activate

'Add Final Data
Dim HBSArray As Range
Set HBSArray = Workbooks("Final SOR.xlsm").Sheets("UsedData").Range("E:L")

Workbooks("Final SOR.xlsm").Sheets("Final Pivot").Activate

Dim UsedID As Range
Set UsedID = Workbooks("Final SOR.xlsm").Sheets("Final Pivot").Range("A:A")


'Enroller Vlookup

Dim EnrollerResult As Range
Set EnrollerResult = Workbooks("Final SOR.xlsm").Sheets("Final Pivot").Range("C:C")

EnrollerResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(UsedID, HBSArray, 3, False)


End Sub
```

to pull over the enroller's name from UsedData Sheet

Comment: `UsedID` Needs to be a single value not a range.  You will need to loop.

Comment: Thanks, It worked perfectly!